# Java- In inheritance, method can be invoked without creating a class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have parent and child classes in which the parent class has a method- `getData`.  I can call this method directly from the child class with or without creating an object. 
I am wondering how does the method become available in child class without creating an object. (It is not static method either) 
It was my understanding that we have to create an object to access the methods. Can anyone please explain why?

```
 public class testbase {

    public void getData(String Data) throws IOException{
        Properties prop1;

        prop1= new Properties();
        FileInputStream f= new FileInputStream("C:\\file.properties");
        prop1.load(f);


        String data= prop1.getProperty(Data);
        System.out.println(data);
    }

}


class testproperties_file extends testbase {

    @Test
    public void test_class() throws IOException{
        getData("name");

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *"without creating an object"*? You create an instance of `testproperties_file` don't you?

Comment: A Child instance **is** a Parent instance. That's the whole point of inheritance. If an animal can run, than I can ask a dog to run, because a dog is an animal.

Comment: When the execution is in child class the invokation is on `this`.  It refers to current object.  And when you invoke the `test_class` method, it will be invoked on the object of `testproperties_file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering how can the method gets available in child class
>   without creating an object.

```
class testproperties_file extends testbase {
    @Test
    public void test_class() throws IOException{
       getData("name");

    }
}
```

Here  `test_class()` is an instance method. It means that all code invoked in this method may invoked methods available for an instance of the current class (here `testproperties_file`). So, you are already in a object when this method is executing.

A instance of  `testproperties_file` inherits from the `testbase` class.
It means that all public and protected instance methods of `testbase` may be invoked here.  The public `getData()` instance method of `testbase` is so callable.

---

As a side note you should use uppercase and camelcase to name your class.
`TestBase` and `TestPropertiesFile` are better as they follow the java coding convention.

Answer (score 1):

As per

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

> > A subclass inherits all the members (fields,**methods**, and nested classes) from its superclass. Constructors are not members, so they are not inherited by subclasses, but the constructor of the superclass can be invoked from the subclass.

I would suggest you to read more abour `inheritance`

Sub child inherits all the member methods from its super class.

If execution control reaches any non static method , it implies there is an object created and upon it that method is being invoked. `this` is the implicit reference to the currently executing object upon which any method is invoked. As the object of derived class has the behaviour of super class, then more behaviours gets added as per the defination of actual derived class and also if any behaviour is overriden then the behaviour derieved from super class gets modified.